# How to decipher dropped packet from packet-tracer output?

Tags: cisco-asa, acl

I have a massive ACL that i'm dealing with and I can't seem to find what line is blocking me. Is there a way for packet-tracer to help me figure out more specifically where i'm getting blocked at?

```
packet-tracer input AAAA tcp 10.A.B.1 5555 10.C.D.80 PORT# d

Phase: 3
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in   0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         AAAA

Phase: 4
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: 
Result: DROP
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:
 Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
 in  id=0x7ffd9a7f9e40, priority=111, domain=permit, deny=true
        hits=28704780, user_data=0x0, cs_id=0x0, flags=0x4000, protocol=0
        src ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, tag=0
        dst ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, tag=0 dscp=0x0
        input_ifc=AAAA, output_ifc=AAAA

Result:
input-interface: AAAA
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: AAAA
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

Some clues that I have gathered (not sure if they are correct though)

- The drop reason indicates that a configured line is dropping the packet and not the default deny at the end
- The packet is getting denied at the output ACL on interface AAAA
- There is a id string and a hit counter but I don't know how to match that up with anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Implicit Rule` and `AAAA` being the in and out interface... That's called *hair-pinning*, and it's generally not allowed.  It works on my asa, but I have the following enabled:

```
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
```

Comment: That makes sense but "same-security-traffic permit inter-interface" is enabled on this firewall, could the block be that the intra-interface isn't enabled?

Comment: @evolvd, yes. To allow traffic to enter and exit the same interface, you need the "intra-interface" statement (see [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/refgd/s1.html#wp1383263) for more details). The "inter-interface" command allows traffic to enter and exit two different interfaces that have the same security level.

Answer (score -1):

[Cisco ASA (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001108.htm)

Pete

Comment: Could you please edit your post to provide more details from the link? To avoid problems with link rot, the community prefers that you [quote important content and provide the link as reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/244349) whenever possible.